# left_joins the same table twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Is it possible to join the same table twice?

In our case we want:

```
  polymorphic.left_joins(:course, step: :course)
```

Problem when polymorphic row has a type "Step" in such case associated course of step does not join

**Why do you need to join it twice?**

For example we have a Polymorphic model that belongs to either a Course model or a Step model.  Step belongs_to course. We should join `course` or `step with course`. It means if Polymorphic row has type `Course` we join  course.fields if type `Step` we need to join `steps with course` so we can have in one row polymorphic.fields + steps.fields +  associated course.fields

Comment: it's very sad to get -1 without any explanation

Comment: Why do you need to join it twice? What are you trying to achieve? Do you have incorrect result in current implementation?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

⚙ We can join the same table twice manually using alias for table (**t1**) 
⛄

```
sql = <<-SQL
  LEFT JOIN courses
    ON courses.id = polymorphicable_id
    AND (polymorphicable_type = 'Course')
  LEFT JOIN steps
    ON steps.id = polymorphicable_id
    AND (polymorphicable_type = 'Step')
  LEFT JOIN courses AS t1
    ON t1.id = steps.course_id
SQL

polymorphic.joins(sql)
```